# Is it possible to run Apache for one domain and Lighttpd for another domain on one server?

Tags: apache, lighttpd

Hello to every professional !
I have Apache running on standard 80 port what serves most of the domains/subdomains on a dedicated server.
But I need to install Lighttpd on the same server to serve ONE specific domain and it's subdomains - separately from Apache.

My first question - is it POSSIBLE under one physical dedicated server ?
The second question - IF it's possible - how to separate them ?
What basic settings must be for Lighttpd then ?
(I've heard Apache could run on 80 port as always and Lighttpd on 81 port, something like that)

Have somebody a real knowledge about a such symbiosis ?
Have a nice day !

Answer (score 1):

Apache and Lighttpd are just 2 servers, you can run them together like any other two servers, as long as they listen to different ports. I don't have experience with Apache and Lighttpd but with Apache and Nginx and it worked perfectly fine.

Just install both servers and make sure you specify the correct ports. Otherwise if one of them would try to register already used ports it would fail. Afterwards just start them up and enjoy.

In Apache you can specify the ports it should listen to in `ports.conf` as `Listen <PortNumber>` more to it here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/bind.html

I don't know much about Lighttpd but there is a SO question which shows a sample configuration how to edit the ports: [Make lighttpd listen on multiple ports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14331794/make-lighttpd-listen-on-multiple-ports)